# Why is template template function overload chosen over the one with the concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code fails in static_assert:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
concept container_type = requires(T& t) {
    typename T::value_type;
    typename T::reference;
    typename T::iterator;
    { t.begin() } -> std::same_as<typename T::iterator>;
    { t.end() } -> std::same_as<typename T::iterator>; 
};

// overload (0), fallback case
template <typename T>
constexpr int foo(const T& o) {
    return 0;
}

// overload (1), using the concept
constexpr int foo(const container_type auto& o) {
    return 1;
}

// overload (2), using template template parameter
template <typename T, template <typename ...> typename C > 
constexpr int foo(const C<T>& o) {
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a {1,3,3,44,55,5,66,76};
    static_assert(foo(a) == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler used is GCC on https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com, command line is `g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread`.

I would expect that the overload (1) should be used as the best match, but overload (2) is used instead.

Is this standard conformant behavior?

Comment: I presume that overload 1 gets picked if overload 2 is commented out (nothing wrong with the concept itself). If so, there must be something about that template definition that makes it more specific than the general concept. Overload resolution rules get very convoluted, very quickly.

Comment: Let's put it this way: concepts break ties between functionally equivalent (in the template definition sense) overloads. The "ancient" rules of partial ordering for templates didn't go away, and just like (2) is chosen over (0) in C++17, it is chosen over (1). The concept merely breaks the tie between (0) and (1).

Comment: Is there any way to circumvent this, by writing the concept differently, for example?

Comment: Yeah, interesting. (2) is more specialized than (1) even though it's not the case that every valid specialization of the function type (2) corresponds to a valid specialization of the function type (1). Unfortunate, since I'd say that's supposed to be the whole point of language specialization ordering.

Comment: Circumvent this? No, you can't. That's how the language works, fundamentally. Partial ordering *must* still work as it always it. Or would you prefer your tried and tested, decade old codebase suddenly break? Imagine you upgrade to C++20 and vastly different overloads get chosen because someone used a concept in a newer library version. Your code may suddenly not build with cryptic errors; or worse, build and execute completely different logic. It'd be very bad if you or I could circumvent those rules. You can however try to write different overload sets, if you can modify *all* the overloads.

Comment: Yes, workaround: Add an additional overload more specialized than all of them, and define it to redirect. `template <typename T, template <typename...> typename C> requires container_type<C<T>> constexpr int foo(const C<T>& o) { return foo<C<T>>(o); }`. (Luckily (2) doesn't match the redirecting call. If it did, you'd want both to redirect to a private common implementation.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Constraints are considered for the purpose of choosing between two viable overloads only if there is no other tie breaker between the overloads, considered as unconstrained. In particular that means that if one is more specialized by the old partial ordering rules for function templates, ignoring constraints, then that will be chosen and constraints are not relevant.

Basically the constraints only matter when comparing function templates that are, except for the constraints, exactly equivalent in terms of their function parameters.

Leaving out the constraint (which is satisfied with the `foo(a)` call in `main`) your first overload looks like

```
constexpr int foo(const auto& o) {
    return 1;
}
```

Now if you compare this to the second overload I think it should be clear that by the usual partial ordering rules for function templates this is less specialized than the second overload. As a consequence the second overload is chosen.

Even if you recast the conditions under which the second overload is valid into a concept `Overload2Concept` and then use

```
constexpr int foo(const Overload2Concept auto& o) {
    return 2;
}
```

instead, it won't work, because the constraints of the two overloads are not subsets of one another. You can have a `container_type` per your definition which is not a specialization of a template and you can have a specialization of a template `template <typename ...> class C;` which is not a `container_type`.

So in that case neither would be more specialized than the other, neither by old partial ordering rules nor by new constraint ordering rules, and consequently overload resolution would be ambiguous.

---

Having concepts/constraints integrated into overload resolution in this way guarantees that adding additional overloads with constraints to pre-C++20 code won't cause any break in the way overloads were chosen beforehand. Were constraints allowed to overrule the old partial ordering in the way you seem to expect, then it would be dangerous to modify any pre-C++20 overload set of functions with constraints.

---

The following overload would be preferred over overload (2) because it is more specialized per constraints and the unconstrained equivalents identical:

```
template <typename T, template <typename ...> typename C >
requires container_type<C<T>>
constexpr int foo(const C<T>& o) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Also useful is `requires !container_type<C<T>>`, which lets you explicitly remove the `container_type` case.  Doesn't scale well however.